# SQL server : Convert rows into columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Output from CTE:

```
colName
-----------------------
branch1    
branch1    
branch1    
unclassified
```

I want to convert the rows into columns like:

```
 colName         colName    colName    colName
 ---------------------------------------------
 unclassified    branch1    branch1    branch1
```

Please let me know the best approach for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to **Convert** rather than **Conert**?

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your full query I would suggest adding a `row_number()` to your CTE and then [pivoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data based on the row number:

```
;with cte as
(
    select *,  -- replace * with your column names
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by colName order by colName) rn
    from yourdata
)
select [1] as colName1, 
    [2] as colName2, 
    [3] as colName3, 
    [4] as colName4
from cte
pivot
(
    max(colName)
    for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

If you do not want to use the PIVOT function, then you could also use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
;with cte as
(
    select *,  -- replace * with your column names
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by colName order by colName) rn
    from yourdata
)
select 
    MAX(case when rn = 1 then colName end) colName1,
    MAX(case when rn = 2 then colName end) colName2,
    MAX(case when rn = 3 then colName end) colName3,
    MAX(case when rn = 4 then colName end) colName4
from cte
-- group by other columns in select if needed
```

Comment: This is it exactly.  Read-up on the [T-SQL Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option in a FROM statement.