# convert strings in a column form to row form

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of strings
eg:

```
'string1'
,'string2'
,'string3'
,'string4'
,'string5'
,'string6'
```

I would like to know if there's a shortcut/key to convert it into a single row 
eg:

```
'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6'
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "list" in SQL Server.  What do you really mean?  (Okay, there is a list for `IN` with constants, but that does not seem to be what you mean.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server : Convert rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589282/sql-server-convert-rows-into-columns)

Comment: Sorry Gordon, what I meant was that on the query window when writing my codes, I'd like to convert these strings for better visibility. For example there's the Shift + Alt + arrow key + ',' for adding commas to multiple lines. What I wanted is something with similar function for convenience.

Comment: To be honest what you have is much easier to read than all the values crammed into a single line.

Comment: Find/Replace can accept regular expressions. You could do something like `[\r\n],` for the "Find what:" input, and `,` for the "Replace with:" portion. As far as a hotkey to do that, /shrug.

Comment: Xedni, thanks I'll try that! Sean Lange, the number of strings I have is very large making it harder to read since I'd have to scroll alot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have list of `String` Values as below :

```
'string1'
,'string2'
,'string3'
,'string4'
,'string5'
,'string6'
```

And, you are looking it in below format :

```
'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6'
```

If, all are correct you could use `XML` method to Display it in Single Row by Using `SQL` Command  as below :

```
SELECT ''+<column_name> FROM <table_name> FOR XML PATH('')
```

**Result :**

```
'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6'
```

**Note** : The above O/P is as per Data provided.