# Move duplicate values of a row to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following sample data:

```
Name            Value
-----------------------
Year            1990
Year            1991
Year            1992
Cash            2000
Cash            4000
Cash            6000
Tax             Paid
Tax             Unpaid
Tax             Pending
Liability       3500
Liability       8500
Liability       9500
```

I want that data in the following format:

```
Name            Value1        Value2        Value3
-----------------------------------------------------
Year            1990          1991          1992
Cash            2000          4000          6000
Tax             Paid          Unpaid        Pending
Liability       3500          8500          9500
```

Please note, the number of columns in result table should be dynamic i.e., number of value columns = number of records for an item in original table.

In the example, each item has 3 records so there will be 3 value columns in result table.

Please guide.

Update:

I used below query and it returned data in correct format, but still clueless how to identify number of columns in resultant table. In below example fixed 5 columns are there (name, value1, value2, value3, value4).

```
with cte as
(
 select name ci,value,
        row_number() over(partition by [name] order by value) as rn
 from TABLE
)
select distinct ci as [name],
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=1) value1,
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=2) value2,
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=3) value3,
       (select ct.value from cte ct where ct.ci=cte.ci and ct.rn=4) value4
from cte
```

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Comment: What if there are 4 rows, or 5? What baout 10? Is it at most always 3? What didn't work in your attempts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL server : Convert rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16589282/2029983)

Comment: Hi @Larnu, number of rows are not fixed. It can be 4,5 or 10. I guess, Pivot will not help as we do not have to transpose all "Name" to column but "values" to columns.

Comment: Then you need a dynamic Pivot, there's 100's if examples of these on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #t
(
Name varchar(50),
Value varchar(50)
)
insert into #t(Name, Value)
values
('Year', '1990'),
('Year', '1991'),
('Year', '1992'),
('Cash', '2000'),
('Cash', '4000'),
('Cash', '6000'),
('Tax', ' Paid'),
('Tax', ' Unpaid'),
('Tax', ' Pending'),
('Liability', '3500'),
('Liability', '8500'),
('Liability', '9500'),
('Liability', '1500'),
('Liability', '2500'),
('Liability', '4500');


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = stuff(
(
select ',[value'+cast(rownum as varchar(20))+']'
from
(
select top((select max(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt from #t group by Name) as t)) row_number() over(order by a.v) as rownum
from 
(
values(cast(null as bit)),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
) as a(v)
cross join
(
values(cast(null as bit)),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
) as b(v)
cross join
(
values(cast(null as bit)),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
) as c(v)
) as nums
order by rownum
for xml path('')), 1, 1, N'');

select @sql = N'
select *
from
(
select *, ''value''+cast(row_number() over(partition by Name order by (select null)) as varchar(20)) as colname
from #t
) as t
pivot
(
max(value) for colname in (' + @sql + N')
) as unpv
';

exec(@sql);

--
drop table #t;
```